# Quick question about the post: $G=N \times K$, $M$ normal subgroup of $N$ implies $M$ normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-homomorphism

In the following post: [$G$ a group, $G=N \times K$, $M$ normal subgroup of $N \Rightarrow$ $M$ normal subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347913/g-a-group-g-n-times-k-m-normal-subgroup-of-n-rightarrow-m-normal-s)

Dan Shved states in his response

> We can build a map $\varphi: G \to (N/M) \times K$ defined like this:
> $$
> \varphi(nk) = (nM, k) \qquad \textrm{for all }\ n \in N,\ k \in K
> $$ It is easy to see that $\varphi$ is well defined and is a homomorphism, and $M$ is its kernel.

The kernel for $\varphi$ would be $$\varphi(nk) = (nM, k)=(M,e)\in M\times \{e\}\cong M.$$  But in set builder notation, do I write

$$\text{Ker }\varphi=\{nk\in G: \varphi(nk)=(nM,k)=(M,e), n\in N, k\in K\}?$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: That just makes things look terrible. Why would you want to do this? The kernel are the $g\in G$ with $\phi(g)=(M,e)$. Adding "$(nM,k)$" in the middle is useless and crowds the expression for absolutely no reason and no gain. Writing $nk\in G$ elides the fact that *every* element of $G$ can  be written this way, which makes one wonder what to do with unequal representations, if any; but it all just begs the question... why do you think you need to write out some sort of "set builder notation" to express this set, other than as $\{g\in G\mid \phi(g)=(M,e)\}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought the convention is to usually write out the full expression for the function.  Thank you for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function, for any $k\in G$, given by

$$\begin{align}
\rho_k: G&\to G,\\
n&\mapsto nk
\end{align}$$

is a bijection; therefore, nothing is lost in writing

$$\ker (\varphi)=\{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)=(M, e)\}.$$

Comment: thank you for the explanation.